# iOS - How can I run unit/ui tests on Release scheme

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, release

I wonder if there is a way to run iOS AppTests and AppUITests on `Release` build. I found SO post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42583703/1084174) where OP mentioned,

> However, the tests cannot run on the release build (because release
>   doesn't build for testing).

Seems he was unable to run tests in Release build. I am also getting some linking errors in Release build while testing but tests run fine on Debug build.

Comment: What are the link errors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in that answer, the code should be the same in release or debug mode. So unit tests should not require running in a release build, specifically.

For the UI tests, if this means your code has conditional compilation based on Release or Debug target, then you might be forced to test some end-to-end tests?

### Option ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45875959/how-to-enable-testability-for-framework-in-release-mode))

**Warning: Apple does not recommend doing this in the xcode [release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-CH1-SW326)**:

```
The Enable Testability build setting should be used only in your Debug configuration,
because it prohibits optimizations that depend on not exporting
internal symbols from the app or framework
```

In the project settings: **Build Settings > Enable Testability**

[image: Enable testability]

This will allow the `@testable` keyword to import the app in your test code.

Then edit the Test scheme to build the Release target
[image: Edit scheme]

[image: Change target in scheme]